# Two browsers on different machines view the same page

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am thinking of a remote help application where a user needs help navigating a web site.

How can a second user see what the first user is seeing so they can help them over the phone.

Could both users interact with the website?

Is there a solution that will work in any browser that requires no special downloads. I can imagine a simple system where the user browser updates the server with the current location URL but how to see the mouse clicks and dynamic Javascript changes etc.

Edit: This is called "cobrowsing" see wikipedia for a list of solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unblu allows two users to interact with the same website

- requires no download
- works with Javascript/AJAX etc
- works of SSL
- can be either cloud or privately hosted

There are others that I have not investigated - you can see a list in the cobrowsing wikipedia page.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an existing screen-sharing solution, like http://join.me ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is a helpdesk offering customers telephone support for filling out large forms on a specific website. I don't think a third party site would be acceptable to the business and I don't think the customer should have to download anything. Maybe I'm asking too much.

Comment: I have since found a few solutions like unblu cobrowsing which does not require any Java/.Net or other downloads for the client to use it. This has the advantage over join.me as it does not require download and it can be hosted (ie non-cloud) which is good for Data Protections Issues etc.